# Moment format returning 'invalid date'

Tags: javascript, typescript, momentjs

I have the following:

```
const input: string = '2021-11-2T10:20:00+01:00';

const date: string = moment( input ).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
const time: string = moment( input ).format('HH:mm');
```

Please can someone tell me why I get 'invalid date' returned for both 'date' and 'time'?

From what I understand the 'input' string is a standard date format (moment gave me this format).

Comment: I pasted this code in my console while on momentjs.com, and I did't get this error. I just got this : `Deprecation warning: value provided is not in a recognized RFC2822 or ISO format. moment construction falls back to js Date(), which is not reliable across all browsers and versions. Non RFC2822/ISO date formats are discouraged. Please refer to http://momentjs.com/guides/#/warnings/js-date/ for more info.`

Comment: Hmmm. i just did ```moment().format();``` and used this value returned as the "input" value and it works. i guess there was something wrong with the date I was using.

Comment: Let me suggest the [luxon](https://moment.github.io/luxon/#/) library. If moment should break critically that's a good go to.

Answer (score 3):

Take care about leading zeros (required by `RFC2822/ISO` format). You can validate date string using `Date` constructor:

```js
new Date('2021-11-2T10:20:00+01:00') // Invalid Date (because of date = '2' instead of '02')
new Date('2021-11-02T10:20:00+01:00') // Tue Nov 02 2021 11:20:00 GMT+020 (works fine!)
```

Same for `moment` instances:

```js
moment('2021-11-2T10:20:00+01:00') // invalid (error or deprecation warning depends on 'moment' version)
moment('2021-11-02T10:20:00+01:00') // valid
```

UPD: [article about standarts with useful links](https://rdrr.io/cran/anytime/man/iso8601.html)

Answer (score 3):

What you are using is known as timestamptz. There's an error. So timestamptz is in the following format:

```
YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ssZZ
```

You are missing a "0" in your day:

2021-11-**0**2T10:20:00+01:00

Then you can just do:

```
const fullDate = moment('2021-11-02T10:20:00+01:00')
const date = moment( input ).format('YYYY-MM-DD')
const time = moment( input ).format('HH:mm')
```

Notice i removed `: string`. You don't need to define the typing btw. It can be infered.

Answer (score -1):

The input string I was using was somehow not valid. When I used "2021-11-02T14:43:59+00:00" it works fine.

Comment: Yes, exactly as @Xeelley explained. You didn't need to post a second answer, you should mark theirs as accepted instead